# Text line into an separated array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, text

I have txt file with 30 values in line separated with space.

```
12.09.11   0:01   16.2   16.2   16.2    72   11.2   3.1    SE   0.19   3.6    SE   15.9   15.9   15.7   761.8  0.00   0.0   0.001   0.000   20.9    46    8.9   19.8   8.65 1.1902     13    1     56.5    1 
12.09.11   0:02   16.2   16.2   16.2    72   11.2   3.1    SE   0.19   4.0    SE   15.9   15.9   15.7   761.8  0.00   0.0   0.001   0.000   20.9    46    8.9   19.8   8.65 1.1903     23    1    100.0    1 
12.09.11   0:03   16.2   16.2   16.2    72   11.1   3.6    SE   0.21   4.9    SE   15.4   15.9   15.2   761.8  0.00   0.0   0.002   0.000   20.9    46    8.8   19.8   8.65 1.1905     23    1    100.0    1
```

I'm not so good with PHP-array so i stuck with this:

```
<?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("data.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$textline = fgets($file_handle);


print $textline[0] . $textline[1]. $textline[2] . "<BR>";
}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

It gets me the output of 3 first character on line, in this case it looks like:

```
12.
12.
12.
```

But i need tottaly separated data values in arrays, so the output should look like this:

```
12.09.11 0:01 16.2
12.09.11 0:02 16.2
12.09.11 0:03 16.2
```

P.S. Also i need to avoid first 3 lines from reading, it shoudl allways start reading from 4th line.

Any tips or advice how to script it properly ? Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code reads a text file line by line.

```
<?php
    $file = "/tmp/file1.txt";
    $f = fopen($file, "r");
    while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
        print $line;
    }
?>
```

So, the same way, you can use:

```
<?php
    $file = "data.txt";
    $f = fopen($file, "r");
    $myArray = array();
    while ( $line = fgets($f) ) {
        $myArray[] = explode("    ", $line);
    }
    print_r($myArray);
?>
```

Comment: I get it now, i was supose to use explode! so i redone my own script to:
`<?PHP
$file_handle = fopen("data.txt", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
$textline = fgets($file_handle);
$array = explode("   ", $textline);
print $array[0] . $array[1]. $array[2] . "<BR>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>`

Comment: Better to terminate `<br />` this way. :)

Comment: Oh yeah! :) <br /> is right! it was a fasty one on script so i was more wondering on php than on right html :>

Comment: By the way, how can i also avoid 3 first lines from reading ? :o

Comment: Well, you can just add three `fgets($f)` before the `while()`. Crappy way, but works. :)

Comment: Check this out too: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/112336-start-fgets-nth-line.html